# Pintar celda de un dataTable php

Tags: php, javascript, css

Tengo un problema que no he podido dar solución. Tengo una tabla con  3 columnas.

```html
Nombre  |  Nota  |  Rango  |
-------------------------------
Pepe    |   5    | Excelente
María   |   3    | Bueno
Luis    |   1    | Malo
```

Quiero que al ser excelente la celda se pinte de verde, si es bueno azul y malo de rojo, pero esta pintando toda la fila y quiero es que pinte solo las celdas de la columna rango. Tengo este código.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#mitabla').DataTable({ 
"scrollX": true,

 "rowCallback": function( Row, Data) {
    if ( Data[2] == "Excelente" )
    {
        $('td', Row).css('background-color', 'Green');
    }
    else if ( Data[2] == "Bueno" )
    {
        $('td', Row).css('background-color', 'Blue');
    }
    else if ( Data[2] == "Malo" )
    {
        $('td', Row).css('background-color', 'Red');
    }
 },
```

Lo que quiero hacer es posible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que tienes que seleccionar la tercera columna de la fila por el indice y le aplicamos el estilo a esa columna.

Osea, buscamos todos los `td` de `tr` actual y obtenemos el `td` del indice 2 y le aplicamos los estilo.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  $("table").dataTable({
    
    rowCallback:function(row,data)
    {
      
      if(data[2] == "Excelente")
      {
        $($(row).find("td")[2]).css("background-color","green");
      }
      else if(data[2] == "Bueno"){
          $($(row).find("td")[2]).css("background-color","blue");
      }
      else{
          $($(row).find("td")[2]).css("background-color","red");
      }
      
    }
    
  });
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script> 

  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>
          Nombre
        </th>
        <th>
          Nota
        </th>
        <th>
          Rango
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Pepe</td>   <td>  5   </td>
        <td>Excelente</td>
      </tr>
            <tr>
        <td>María   </td>   <td> 3   </td>
        <td>Bueno</td>
      </tr>
                  <tr>
        <td>Luis       </td>   <td> 1   </td>
        <td>Malo</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: Gracias me funcionó.

Comment: Me alegra haberte ayudado.